# What is the relationship between framebuffer, VT, and tty?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, framebuffer, tty

I'm now studying what is the mechanism behind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>~<kbd>F7</kbd>.

I found some infomation talk about framebuffer, VT, and tty. I know framebuffer is an anstraction to graphic card manipulation and tty(and pts) is something a program interact with. I also find some people talking about VT(virtual terminal), but I don't know what is the relationship between them.

After searching on the web, I made a figure.

[image: figure]

I think a VT is a set of monitor and keyboard. If I want to use many tty in one set(one VT), I have to switch between ttys because I only have one monitor to show them. This is VT Swich. But what is VT actually be? A driver, a module, or something else?

I guess if I have two set of monitors and keyboards connect to my computer, I can group them to form two VTs. And I can show my tty1 in monitor1 and control it use keyboard1, and tty2 with monitor2 and keyboard2. I can do VT Switch in both VT, too. Is that true?

And I think I can view framebuffer(fbcon + fbdev) as a graphic card driver, but it is design for console, not for general purpose(proprietary drivers).

Also, there are some special files under /dev

`/dev/tty*` and `/dev/pts/*` are for tty
`echo` can send input to the tty, and `cat` can recieve output from the tty.

`/dev/vcs*` are for screen of VT
`cat` can get the text in the screen, but use it under X get all zero(not empty).

`/dev/fb*` are for framebuffer
`cat` can get the whole pixel in the screen, but use it under X get all zero(not empty). I heard that X server doesn't use framebuffer, so what does it use?

Please tell me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're correct about tty and pty being terminals, but there is a small difference. A pty is a pseudo-terminals. If you open a terminal and run `tty`, it will return pts terminal. A tty is generally physical if you have used embedded Linux. You can redirect Linux console to different tty which are UART terminals. If you use a 9-pin UART cable, then you can use `ttyX`.
2. vcs are different screens that were used in the pre-X-Server era, or now in the server where X server (or even Wayland Server) is not installed in run levels 3 and 5. Use CTRL + ALT + F3 to access /dev/vc3. You can echo and cat similarly.
3. The framebuffer is part of the Graphic subsystem it's not supposed to be used with cat. It is a matrix; an abstraction over any screen connected to be used by graphical drivers and applications.